# Rotate UIView infinitely and pause/stop animation, keep state, and continue rotating from current state

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview, rotation

I am having a hard time trying to pause and continue from the current state of the rotation any UIView rotation technique.

Tried:

```
CGAffineTransformRotate
CGAffineTransformMakeRotation
CATransform3DMakeRotation
CABasicAnimation
```

Basically, if i call `view.layer.removeAllAnimations()` or, `layer.speed = 0` , they all reset current rotation degree.

Also tried snapshotting the view for using the image instead the true rotation, but with no luck, since the snapshot ignored rotation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally got it, with more than one answer on SO, many in objective-c, put them all together in an UIView extension, and even documented:

```
extension UIView {

        /**
         Will rotate `self` for ever.

         - Parameter duration: The duration in seconds of a complete rotation (360º).
         - Parameter clockwise: If false, will rotate counter-clockwise.
         */
        func startRotating(duration duration: Double, clockwise: Bool) {
            let kAnimationKey = "rotation"
            var currentState = CGFloat(0)

            // Get current state
            if let presentationLayer = layer.presentationLayer(), zValue = presentationLayer.valueForKeyPath("transform.rotation.z"){
                currentState = CGFloat(zValue.floatValue)
            }

            if self.layer.animationForKey(kAnimationKey) == nil {
                let animate = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
                animate.duration = duration
                animate.repeatCount = Float.infinity
                animate.fromValue = currentState //Should the value be nil, will start from 0 a.k.a. "the beginning".
                animate.byValue = clockwise ? Float(M_PI * 2.0) : -Float(M_PI * 2.0)
                self.layer.addAnimation(animate, forKey: kAnimationKey)
            }
        }

        /// Will stop a `startRotating(duration: _, clockwise: _)` instance.
        func stopRotating() {
            let kAnimationKey = "rotation"
            var currentState = CGFloat(0)

            // Get current state
            if let presentationLayer = layer.presentationLayer(), zValue = presentationLayer.valueForKeyPath("transform.rotation.z"){
                currentState = CGFloat(zValue.floatValue)
            }

            if self.layer.animationForKey(kAnimationKey) != nil {
                self.layer.removeAnimationForKey(kAnimationKey)
            }

            // Leave self as it was when stopped.
            layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(currentState, 0, 0, 1)
        }

    }
```

Use it like `yourView.startRotating(duration: 1, clockwise: true)`, later to stop do `yourView.stopRotating()`.